# Not understanding weird behaviours of printf()

Tags: c

I found a question asking for output of the following statement :

```
printf("%d"+1,123);
```

The answer given was `d`, It's explanation was : Since `"%d"` is a string, +1 here means `d`.

`123` just gets ignored.
My first question is : why `123` gets ignored?

I also ran the following statement

```
printf("%d"+2,123);
```

It printed nothing. The code runs but without errors. 
My second question is : why did the code compiled without errors?

Third time, I did following:

```
printf("%d"+0,123);
```

Output was `123`.
So I am getting real confused here. If +1 printed `d`, then shouldn't +0 print `%`?

Comment: `printf("%d"+2,123);` same as `printf("",123);`.  Extra arguments not needed by the format are ignored.

Comment: If you're really new to C, you should know that string literals are implemented as arrays of `char`.  When arrays are used in expressions, the compiler treats the array as a pointer to the first element.  Hence the `+2` advances the pointer by 2 chars.  In C, strings use a "null-terminated" representation, which means the string ends when a `\0` character is encountered, so `"%d"` is effectively the array `{'%', 'd', '\0'}`.  When you advance the pointer 2 chars, you effectively point at the `{'\0'}` portion, which is a string with no characters.  Hence, no output.

Comment: So, why +0 didn't print %?

Comment: `+0` doesn't move the pointer at all, so it is exactly the same as if you hadn't added it.  The first argument to `printf` is a "format specifier".  It tells `printf` how to treat all the following args.  `%d` means "print the corresponding integer argument as signed decimal".  There are many alternatives: e.g., `%X` instructs `printf` to print the corresponding integer argument as hexadecimal digits, using upper-case letters for digits A-F.  An illustrative example is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholder_specification)

Comment: Oh, I get it now! Thank you for helping out. But another question is when I do `printf("%d"+0);` It prints `%`. So why here `%d` worked as a char array and didn't ignored the +0? Why only adding a second argument 123, `%d` was identified as format specifier?

Comment: I just deleted a comment that was incorrect.  I'm not really sure how you got it to print `%`.  `printf` will trust your format specifier, and you told it you were passing an integer (via `%d`) but didn't pass one.  That will give you undefined behavior.  The moment you have a case the C specification permits to be undefined, you can get random or arbitrary behavior...depends on the compiler-  and runtime-library author's implementation choices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine a string:

```
char str[] = "%d";
```

Now we know that:

```
str[0] == '%'
str[1] == 'd'
str[2] == '\0' = 0x00
str+2 == &str[2] == the address of the byte 0x00 inside the str string == ""
printf("%d", 123); is the same as printf(str, 123)
printf("%d" + 2, 123); if the same as printf("", 123); and it will print "", ie. nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

A character point with an addition lead to a character point.

`printf` is just a function

So it takes a variety of parameter - varags

1. "%d"+1 Will be a string just `d`n it
2. "%d"+2 - will be the null byte - nothing
3. "%d"+0 - Will be %d - hence expected output - see the manual page

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your first question:
123 gets ignored because while writing printf("%d"+1,123), +1 places the pointer at index 1 of %d i.e d. Since, to print 123 we need the pointer to be at % and access %d and not just d. Hence, only d gets printed out in this case.

Answer to your second question 
It compiled without error because printf() is just a function and it takes various arguments. For more details about printf() you can visit [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Streams-and-File-Descriptors)

And in the third case i.e printf("%d"+0,123), the output is 123 because here the pointer's position is at 0 i.e at % and we have access to %d. Hence, we're getting 123 as output.

hope this will help you.